# How to get rid of third-party library warnings while running unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I setup my project using PyScaffold and while running unit tests using pytest I get the following third party warning that I'd like to get rid of but don't know how:

```
==================================== warnings summary ====================================
c:\dev\pyrepo\lib\site-packages\patsy\constraint.py:13
  c:\dev\pyrepo\lib\site-packages\patsy\constraint.py:13: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing
 the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in
 3.9 it will stop working
    from collections import Mapping

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
```

What's the best way to avoid warnings from third-party libraries like this but not my own project code warnings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to suppress warnings:

- using command-line arguments

To hide the warning completely use

```
pytest . -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

This command will hide `warnings summary` but will show `1 passed, 1 warning` message

```
pytest . --disable-warnings
```

- creating `pytest.ini` with the following content

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

You can also use regex patterns:

```
ignore:.*U.*mode is deprecated:DeprecationWarning
```

From the docs:

> This will ignore all warnings of type DeprecationWarning where the start of the message matches the regular expression `.*U.*mode is deprecated`.

- marking your `test_` function with `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings("ignore::DeprecationWarning")`
- using `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment  variable

```
PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::DeprecationWarning" pytest .
```

It has the same syntax as the `-W` command-line arg. More [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONWARNINGS).

More details can be found in the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html)